# Scrollspy links don't activate when scrolling throught the relative text

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Let me begin by saying that I'm a beginner.

I can't figure out why the scrollspy is not working on my page. It contains nav-pills stacked on the left, the problem is that they don't respond when scrolling through the main text. After trying and trying I came to the conclusion that the problem must be something related to the css but I'm not sure of it...

Jquery and Bootstrap are loaded in the CodePen settings.

I checked the browser's console: it shows 36 warnings related to the image source safety although I don't believe that the problem is that one.

Here is the code

```
 <body data-spy="scroll" data-target="#myScrollspy" data-offset="50">
<div class="jumbotron">
  <h1>Kurt Angle</h1>
  <p>Olympic Gold Medalist, World Champion, Hall of Famer, Living Legend</p></div>

<!--CAROUSEL BEGINES-->
<div class="fluid-container">
  <div class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel" data-pause="false" id="carousel">

    <!--indicators--->
    <ol class="carousel-indicators">
      <li data-target="#carousel" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
      <li data-target="#carousel" data-slide-to="1"></li>
      <li data-target="#carousel" data-slide-to="2"></li>
      <li data-target="#carousel" data-slide-to="3"></li>
    </ol>

    <!--wrapper of the images(itmes)--->
    <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
      <div class="item active">
        <img src="http://b.fssta.com/uploads/content/dam/fsdigital/fscom/Buzzer/Images/2016/07/29/073116%20kurt%20angle.vresize.1200.630.high.0.jpg" alt="slide1" class="img-responsive">
        <div class="carousel-caption">
          <h3>Olympic Games 1996</h3>
          <p>Kurt Angle celebrates the <b>gold medal</b>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="item">
        <img src="http://b.fssta.com/uploads/2017/01/kurt.vresize.1200.630.high.0.jpg" alt="slide2" class="img-responsive">
      <div class="carousel-caption">
        <h3>2000</h3>
        <p>Angle is the <b>WWE Champion</b></p>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="item">
        <img src="http://b.fssta.com/uploads/2017/01/Kurt-Angle-3-1.vresize.1200.630.high.0.jpg" alt="slide3" class="img-responsive">
        <div class="carousel-caption">
          <h3>May 29 2009</h3>
          <p><b>ECW debut</b></p> 
        </div>
      </div>


   <div class="item">
        <img src="http://img.wennermedia.com/social/kurt_angle_bio-25d61b10-3182-46f3-850c-9b68d29f91b6.png" alt="slide4"class="img-responsive">
     <div class="carousel-caption">
       <h3>2017</h3>
       <p><b>WWE Hall of Fame inductee</b></p>
     </div>

      </div> 

    <!--now let's put right and left control-->
    <a class="left carousel-control" href="#carousel" role="button" data-slide="prev">
      <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left" aria-hidden="true"></span>
      <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>

<a class="right carousel-control" href="#carousel" role="button" data-slide="next">
  <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right" aria-hidden="true"></span>
  <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
      </a>
      </div>

<!--SCROLLSPY & AFFIX (VERTICAL SIDENAV)>-->
        <div class="container">
      <div class="row">
        <nav class="col-sm-3" id="myScrollspy">
          <ul class="nav nav-pills nav-stacked" data-spy="affix" data-offset-top="1000">
            <li class="active"><a href="#aw">Amateur Wrestling</a></li>
              <li><a href="#wwe">WWE</a></li>
                <li><a href="#tna">TNA</a></li>
                  </ul>
                </nav>
                <div class="col-sm-9">
                  <h1>Here is a timeline of Kurt's amateur and professional wrestling career:</h1>
                    <div id="aw">
                   <h2>Amateur Wrestling</h2>
                     <ul id="ulAW">
                       <li><p><b>1987</b> 
                         <ul>
                           <li><p> he is the Senior Pennsylvania State Wrestling Champion and</p></li>
                           <li><p>USA Junior Freestyle champion</p></li>
                         </ul>
                           <li><p><b>1988 -</b> USA International Federation of Associated Wrestling Styles Junior World Freestyle champion</p></li> 
                         <li><p><b>1991 -</b> 2-time National Collegiate Athletic Association Division I champion, national runner-up and a 3-time NCAA Division I All-American</p></li>
                       <li><p><b>1995 -</b> Angle wins the gold medal at the Fila World Championship Wrestling in Atalanta, Georgia</p></li>
                         <li><p><b>1996 - enters the Olympic Games and wins the gold medal</b></p></li>
                         </ul>
                         </div>
                  <div id="wwe">
                    <h2>WWE|1998-2006|title wins</h2>
                    <ul id="ulwwe">
                      <li><b>2000</b>
                        <ul>
                          <li>10/2 RAW - wins the <b>European title</b> against Val Venis</li>
                      <li>27/2 No Way Out - wins the <b>Intercontinental Championship</b> against Chris Jericho</li>
                        <li>22/10 No Mercy - becomes <b>WWE Champion</b> by beating The Rock in a No DQ match</li>
                        </ul>
                      </li>
                      <li><b>2001</b>
                        <ul>
                          <li>27/4 Smackdown - wins the <b>WCW Championship</b> from Booker T</li>
                          <li><p>23/9 Unforgiven - becomes <b>2-times WWE Champion</b> by defeating non other than Stone Cold Steve Austin</p></li>
                          <li><p>beats Rhyno and wins the <b>United States Championship</b></p></li>
                        </ul></li>
                  <li><b>2002</b>
                    <ul>
                      <li><p>20/10 No Mercy - along with Chris Benoit wins for the first the <b>WWE Tag Team Championship</b></p></li>
                      <li><p> 15/12 Armageddon - after beating Big Show, Angle is <b>3-times WWE Champion</b></p></li>
                    </ul>
                  </li>
                  <li><b>2003</b>
                    <ul>
                      <li><p>27/2 Vengeance - beats Brock Lesnar and Big Show to become <b>WWE Champion for the 4th</b> time</p></li></ul></li>
                  <li><b>2006</b>
                    <ul>
                      <li><p>10/1 Returns to Smackdown to win the 20-man battle royal and win the vacant <b>World Heavyweight Championship</b></p></li>
                    </ul>
                    </ul>
                  </div>
                  <div id="tna">
                    <h2>TNA|2006-2016|title wins</h2>
                    <ul id="ultna">
                      <li><b>2007</b>
                        <ul>
                          <li><p>13/5 Sacrifice - Kurt becomes <b>TNA World Champion</b></p></li>
                          <li><p>17/6 Slammiversary - wins for the <b>second time</b> the championship in a </p>
                            <p>king of the Mountain match</p></li>
                          <li><p>25/10 iMPACT! - wins back the title from Sting, becoming  3-times world champion</p></li></ul></li>
                      <li><p><b>2009</b> - 21/6 Slammiversary - again wins the King of The Mountain match and becomes <b>TNA Champion</b></p></li>
                      <li><p><b>2011</b> - 7/8 HardCORE Justice - wins the World championship from Sting</p></li>
                      <li><p><b>2012</b> - 10/6 Slammiversary - wins the <b>TNA Tag Team Championship</b> with AJ Styles</p></li>
                      <li><p><b>2015</b> - 20/3 IMPACT Wrestling - wins the TNA World Championship from Bobby Lashley</p></li>
                    </ul>
                    </div>
        </div>
      </div>
          </div>
```

[CodePen demonstration](https://codepen.io/davide2894/pen/jByzKy?editors=1100)

Let's try to understand what's going on here, it's frustrating to be stuck on these simple things and not understanding the problem but it's quite rewarding when the solution is found.

Comment: Have you tried a minimal example with just a simple scrollspy and nav?

Comment: Hey! I just tried now but nothing, it doesn't work. I noticed that when i scroll over the nav it disappears instead of getting  in a lower position

Comment: @ZimSystem I solved the problem: I isolated it and it was the body{position: relative;}. After I deleted it it's working. Do you perhaps know why? p.s. I feel freaking awesome for solving the problem by myself :D I analyzed every single line of code, compared it with the w3s bootstrap example, then created a reduced test case on codepen, isolated the code and compared line after line hahaha